# toDataURL(); not saving image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm having issues with the `toDataURL();` method. I am trying to save an image of the canvas so that when I resize my browser/canvas, it can appear on the back on my canvas again (as a workaround since whenever you set the width of the canvas, it clears it) and then continue my "draw" function that I have written, but on a different sized canvas. This way, it will seem like I can seamlessly resize the canvas without clearing it.

In my code, `toDataURL();` either doesn't seem to be saving an image or perhaps I am calling it out wrong when I am resizing the canvas. I checked with just setting the source as a normal .png file and that seemed to draw properly in the back. I found this question asked before, but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer...

**JS**

```
  canvas.onmousemove = draw;
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var video = document.createElement("video");
       video.setAttribute("src", "some_video.mp4");
       video.autoplay = true;
       var img2 = new Image;
       img2.src = "some_image.png";
       var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
       ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
       ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  function draw(e){
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
           var x = e.clientX-rect.left-img2.width/2;
           var y = e.clientY-rect.top-img2.height/2;
           ctx.drawImage(video, x, y, 830, 644);
           ctx.drawImage(img2, x, y, img2.width, img2.height);
  }

   $(window).resize(function(){
            var image = new Image;
            image.src = dataURL; 
            ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            draw();
        });
```

Comment: Your question has been asked & answered many, many times so I'm astonished you couldn't find any previous posts. You need to wait for the image to load before trying to `drawImage` it. Also, your `var dataURL` seems to be capturing the canvas before anything has been drawn on it.

Comment: Because when you call `toDataURL()` method, the canvas has nothing. Call it after image has been drawn to the canvas.

Comment: @Leo. That's what I said in my comment, too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you intend to do with the clipped content as your code  will dump all pixels that go below and to the right of the new canvas resolution if the resize is down. So I think you have not thought it through.

What you need to do is keep the canvas off screen, set to the resolution you want. Then use the display canvas just as a view that you render to, and a event target for your mouse input, and do all you draw functions on the off screen canvas. That way you can resize all you want and not have to use toDataURL (it was not intended for that type of use as the resize event can fire many times a second and toDataURL encode and decode will not keep up)

To create an off screen canvas

```
var can = document.createElement("canvas");
can.width = width;
can.height = height;
ctx = can.getContext("2d");
```

Render it to the on screen canvas whenever you update the offscreen one, or resize the window.

```
scrCtx.drawImage(can,0,0); //scrCtx is the on screen ctx
```

You also get the added benefit of being able to zoom, pan and rotate the view without affecting the background image quality. It's fast. toDataURL is intended for data transport over networks and storage devices, not as a ram buffer.